# How to convert a NSString number to a 3 digit percentage value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, nsstring

I have a NSString that has the following number 0.871 and I'm trying to convert this to display like so 87.1%

I tried to use NSNumberFormatter to get that result but I can't get it to display 3 digits. What's the best way to achieve this result? Thanks.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle];
NSNumber *number = [formatter numberFromString:inputString];
[formatter release];
```

Comment: Just from a quick glance, is `NSNumberFormatterPercentStylee` a typo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString * str = @"0.863";
NSString * newStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f%%", [str floatValue]*100];
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, Short and Sweet code. It works as desired. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to convert a string to a number, then format the number:

```
NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:inputString];

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle];
NSString *formattedString = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
[formatter release];
```

If you just want to turn "0.871" into the number 87.1:

```
NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:inputString];
NSDecimalNumber *percentNumber = [number decimalNumberByMultiplyingByPowerOf10:2];
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, this was the way I wanted to do it. I'll go with Raphael's code due to the simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Just use setMinimumFractionDigits:

```
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.871];

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:1];

NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:myNumber]);     // 87.1%
```

this also ensures that percentages are formatted appropriately for the locale.